# Symfony2: routing and parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I have param in /app/config/parameters.ini:

```
[parameters]
    my_param=123
```

And in my routing.yml file I have next:

```
url_name:
    pattern: /test
    defaults:
        _controller: MyBundle:MyController:test
    requirements:
        url_param_1:  %my_param%
```

I want for url_param_1 be required. If user go to /test - he'll get 404 exception.
If user got to /test?url_param_1=%my_param% (in my example it is /test?url_param_1=123) - all ok.
Can I do it automatically without check validation in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add a slug in your pattern?

```
url_name:
pattern: /test/{url_param_1}
defaults:
    _controller: MyBundle:MyController:test
requirements:
    url_param_1:  %my_param%
```